# Reducing Algebric expressions dynamically using java code

Tags: java

I want to reduce a given expression like below,

**Eg:** `a+(b-c+d)-((a-b)+(b-d)) = a+b-c+d-a+b-b+d`

I want to reduce those brackets and multiple the signs to variables after bracket.
how to do it dynamically? I had stuck with this!!

Comment: The RHS of your example already does this.  What is your question, and how is this related to Java?

Comment: Can you post code what have you tried till now?

Comment: **Computer Algebra** is a broad field and appears to be quite complex.  I'd suggest research first on existing algorthims.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra

Comment: You should specify your question. What is the structure (a group, a ring)? Is it commutative? Do you allow elimination (e.g. `b + a - b = a`)? etc.

Comment: @clemens Yeah it should do those eliminations..

Answer (score 0):

you can use a bottom up approach using regexes,

```
+(f) rewrites to f (or +f if it does not start with a sign)
-(f) rewrites to f with all signs in f reversed
```

f can not contain any brackets (that's the bottom up part)

repeat until all brackets are gone